# SAP FM EPS2_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING file mask

Tags: file, abap, application-server, function-module

The FM EPS2_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING has a parameter file_mask which I guess that it should act as a pattern. I need to read from the AS the files containing a word but the file_mask is working faultly. For example if I pass "*ZIP" it returns a file named '.TXT'. Is there a proper way to use that parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters are described in [SAP note 1860206](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1860206) which I will not quote here because I'm not sure about the copyright status. However, wildcards generally do not work as expected in this case - your best bet is to read without the parameter and filter the table afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but due to poor(eg. * wildcard can be used only at the and of the file mask string :/ ) implementation of standard FILE_MASK-based filtering feature in EPS2_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING I ended up with the solution where I read entire directory content and then process it with regular expressions to find matching files/directories.

Comment: Yes, and also wildcard* is working, so using * at the end. The best matching method I found was by using: DELETE itab WHERE NOT filename CP pattern.